# Bind on C++/CLI delegate in Javascript (WinJS)

Tags: javascript, c++, cordova, winjs

I am building a Cordova application for all major operating systems (iOS, macOS, Android and Windows).

I wrote a native Plugin (WinRT) in C++/CLI to call some native functions, this Plugin uses delegates to asynchronously give back results.

I also wrote a test application in C# that allows me to easily test the C++/CLI code without having to compile the whole Cordova project. 
I am able to bind to the C++/CLI delegate without any issue in C#, but I am not able to do so in Javascript.

C# Way (Works like a charm):

```
myCppClass.log += (string logString) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(logString);
                    };
```

Javascript Way (Does not work at all):

```
myCppClass.addEventListener("log", function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            });
```

I got the Javascript way from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779077.aspx

Does anyone know how to bind to C++/CLI delegates in Javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look once again on the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779077.aspx#Anchor_4 sample.

Have you tried this way?

```
var instance = new MyCppClass();
instance.addEventListener("log", function (e) {
   console.log(e.msg);
});
```